# Can K-means do dimensionality reduction？

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

My question is if we have 10 columns continuous variable,
can we do k-means to shrink 10 columns to 1 with corresponding cluster labels
and then do decision tree or logistic regression?

if a new data comes in, use k-mean result to determine its label and go to the machine learning model.

Answer (score 1):

K-means is absolutely not a dimensionality reduction technique. Dimensionality reduction algorithms map the input space to a lower dimensional input space, while what you are proposing is mapping the input space directly to the output space which consists of the set of all integer labels.

Comment: Hello, Mohammad, first thank you for your answers. My thought would be transfer like
sample 1 [10000,12000,-3200,66333]  to  [1] because it will belong to label one
sample 2 [20000,22000,4700,2600]  to  [2] because it will belong to label one